# Breaking down a JavaScript code into functions

Tags: javascript, helper

Newbie student coder,

Here and  I am developing a program that can alert program that once you type in the amount of money you give it will calculate the tip, and tax to get the total amount that the user owns. I have the base code down and divided it up into functions but when I put in a number it shows as unidentified.

Here is my code:

```
const TAXRATE=.095
const TIPRATE=.2

function foodCharge (foodCharge) {
  return parseFloat(prompt("please enter the amount"));
}
foodCharge ();

function taxAmount (foodCharge,TAXRATE) {
  return parseFloat(foodCharge*TAXRATE);
}

taxAmount();


function subAmount (foodCharge,taxAmount) {
  return parseFloat(foodCharge+taxAmount);
}
subAmount ();

function tipAmount (TAXRATE,subAmount) {
  return parseFloat (TAXRATE*subAmount);
}
tipAmount ();


function grandTotal (foodCharge, taxAmount, tipAmount) {
  return grandTotal=parseFloat(foodCharge+taxAmount+tipAmount)
}
grandTotal ();

function finalCost(foodCharge,taxAmount, tipAmount, grandTotal ) { 
   alert ("Meal cost: "+ foodCharge + " \nTax: " + taxAmount + "  \nTip: " + 
    tipAmount +" \nGrand total: " + grandTotal);
}
finalCost();
```

Comment: All of your functions expect to receive arguments, but when you call them you don't pass any arguments. Also, all but the last function return values that you ignore. So when you call the `finalCost()` function at the end, you don't pass it any arguments, so `foodCharge`, `taxAmount`, etc. are all undefined. Note that you've overused `parseFloat()` - the only place you need that is when the value is a string, i.e., for the value the user enters. By the way, I've formatted the code in your question to make it more readable (changes to whitespace, no change to the actual code).

Comment: please edit your post subject to be more descriptive of the problem and point out what SPECIFICALLY your problem is rather than just say "I can't figure out the problem", I urge you to read the SO posting guidelines

Comment: @shafeen - Why would you edit to remove the demo snippet? Also, the OP did state what the problem is, i.e., that the results show as "undefined" - as was apparent when running the snippet that you removed.

Comment: @nnnnn - is that what happened? when I was editing, there weren't any other edits that I saw, not sure what happened, my bad

Comment: @shafeen - Oh, OK, sometimes StackOverflow gets confused if two people edit at the same time, so that's probably what happened. Sorry to have blamed you.

Comment: @nnnnn - sorry bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ***parseFloat*** function only when you parse float number from string. You don't need to parse result of regular math operation(if both numbers are not strings). When you pass function as a parameter to **alert()** you must pas it with brackets ***()***, otherwise you pass the reference to a function.

If i correctly understand your question, here is your program:

```
const TAXRATE=0.095
const TIPRATE=0.2


function foodCharge (foodCharge) {
  return parseFloat(prompt("please enter the amount"));
}
var charge = foodCharge ();


function taxAmount (charge, rate) {
  return charge*rate;
}
var tax = taxAmount(charge, TAXRATE);


function subAmount (charge,tax) {
  return charge+tax;
}
var amount = subAmount (charge,tax);


function tipAmount (rate,amount) {
  return rate*amount;
}
var tip = tipAmount(TAXRATE,amount);


function grandTotal () {
  return charge+tax+tip;
}


function finalCost() {
  alert ("Meal cost: "+ charge + " \nTax: " + tax + "  \nTip: " + amount +" \nGrand total: " + grandTotal());
}
finalCost();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the function to be called within `finalCost`. Note, `parseFloat()` is only necessary at `foodCharge` function

```js
const TAXRATE = .095
const TIPRATE = .2

function foodCharge() {
  return parseFloat(prompt("please enter the amount"));
}

function taxAmount(charge, tax) {
  return charge * tax;
}

function subAmount(charge, tax) {
  return charge + tax;
}

function tipAmount(tip, sub) {
  return tip * sub;
}

function grandTotal(charge, tax, tip) {
  return charge + tax + tip;
}

function finalCost() {

  let _foodCharge = foodCharge();
  let _taxAmount = taxAmount(_foodCharge, TAXRATE);
  let _subAmount = subAmount(_foodCharge, _taxAmount);
  let _tipAmount = tipAmount(TIPRATE, _subAmount);
  let _grandTotal = grandTotal(_foodCharge, _taxAmount, _tipAmount);

  alert("Meal cost: " + _foodCharge + " \nTax: " + _taxAmount + "  \nTip: " +
    _tipAmount + " \nGrand total: " + _grandTotal);
}

finalCost();
```

Comment: Ok to try and break down your code (to understand this better for future use).... what you did was create functions with all of the original names intact... then in the parenthesis add its own variable ex. charge and tax etc. then in order to pass the argument to the finalCharge function you assigned the charge and tax to each of their respected function ex.let tax = taxAmount(charge, TAXRATE); and that's how you are able to pass an argument in a function

Comment: @NathanCenter Yes. To avoid issue with variables having same identifier the variables withing `finalCost` begin with and underscore.